# Marshaling ushort[,] multidimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, marshalling

I've inherited some code that I need to interface with. Specifically there is a Marshaled command that I want to call from C#. The code call looks like this;

```
[DllImport(DLL_PATH, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void readTable([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ushort[,] buffer);
```

So the 'readTable' command fills in the multidimensional array 'buffer'.

I'm not able to do this very well, but here is my (non-compiling) attempt;

```
ushort[,] myTable = new ushort[5,100];   // multidimensional array

unsafe
{
  fixed (ushort* inputPtr = &myTable[0, 0])
  {
      readTable(inputPtr);
  }
}
```

Obviously not compiling, but I'm too much of a newbie to fix the error.

I really want to declare;

```
fixed(ushort[,]* inputPtr = &myTable)
```

But that is just nonsense.

Anyone understand my plight? Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ushort[,] myTable = new ushort[5,100];
readTable(myTable);
```

Unless `readTable` keeps the pointer after it returns, the marshaler's pinning and unpinning the array will work fine for you.

Comment: Doh! I can't believe I didn't try this - it works just fine. I got stuck into googling how to define the multi-dimensional array first of all (new ushort[5,100]) and came across the fixed and unsafe commands before trying the obvious simple case. Problem solved - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My take:

A multi-dimensional array is just a continuous array of size of all the dimensions.

In your case, the 'C' code will see it as `ushort[5 * 100]`.

To make this work, do the following:

```
ushort[,] myTable = new ushort[5, 100];   // multidimensional array

unsafe
{
  fixed (ushort* inputPtr = myTable)
  {
    readTable(inputPtr);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I dont have time to test this, but it compiles just fine.

Comment: You don't need the `fixed ()` and the `unsafe` if you define your method as `([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ushort[,] buffer)` (as the OP has done), but I have to tell the truth, I haven't ever tried marshaling MD arrays.